# Insert when does not exist but update on a condition if it does

Tags: mysql, sql

I know about `REPLACE` and `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`, the thing is i want to insert if my employee exists and update some columns if it does but based on a conditon.

For eg: My Table columns

```
Id(Auto Generated), EmpId, EmpName, Salary, Version
12                  ABW72  John     1000    100
```

`EmpId` is not the primary key, but has an `Unique Index`

Now if `ABW72` does not exist, an `INSERT` would do
and `UPDATE` if exists for `EmpId = ABW72` only when `version is > 20`. This version is the version stored in DB. How would one do that in MySql.

We tried on the app side with something like this:

```
Step 1: Select with a lock on EmpId=ABW72. A lock would be taken if it exists.
Step 2: If Step1 returned 0 records, Insert Ignore OR Insert
Step 2: If Step1 returned 1 record, just update based on the condition.
```

The problem here is with Step 2, cause if Insert is used it causes exceptions with highly concurrent loads, and Insert Ignore leads to a valid update getting missed.

Comment: in postgres we have UPSERT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use conditional expression in the `on duplicate key update` clause.  Here is an example:

```
insert into mytable(EmpId, EmpName, Salary, Version)
    values ($EmpId, $EmpName, $Salary, $Version)
    on duplicate key update
        EmpName = (case when Version > 20 then Values(EmpName) else EmpName end),
        Salary = (case when Version > 20 then Values(Salary) else Salary end);
```

Comment: This looks good. Can you please help me with the syntax to update multiple columns? Do i have to repeat the version > 20 condition in every case

Comment: @Abhi . . . Yes you do.  Also note that this uses the version stored in the table for the condition, not the value being passed in (your question is not clear on which should be used).

Comment: Updated the question. Yes the version is the one stored in the DB. This is awesome. Let me just quickly test this. Will mark it as the answer, post that. Thanks a lot.